# JSP -- Giving HTTP 500 on form process

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, nullpointerexception

I am writing a small jsp file to parse and validate user input. The html form for testing is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="NewUser.jsp" method="POST">
<label for="usr">user name:</label>
<input type="text" name="usr"><br>
<label for="passwd">password:</label>
<input type="password" name="passwd">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Next is the JSP

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Complete</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    out.write(request.getParameter("user"));
    out.write(request.getParameter("passwd"));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, my error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.NewUser_jsp._jspService(NewUser_jsp.java:72)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

I don't understand. what is null? I have attempted to change the method to GET, but that was no fix. My tomcat version is listed in the error. If it helps, my Tomcat was intalled through Eclipse.

Comment: Post your real code. This is not the code that's throwing the exception. Unless something major changed between Tomcat 5 and Tomcat 7 with respect to `out.write`. Have you tried `out.print` instead?

Comment: What is my real code ?? I have one other java class, but it is not even used yet.

Comment: You can only get a null pointer exception by using the . operator on a variable that's null. `request.getParameter("user")` can't give you that error just because the parameter is null, but `request.getParameter("user").toUpperCase()` can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use request.gerParameter("usr") not "user" . Your input field has the string usr defined for the the first input

Comment: Whoops. I'm embarrased.